# Can i send command from the client to active directory with script?

Tags: active-directory, command, remote-access

I create the gpo for one active directory but i cant find if is enable or not to send commands from the client so active directory.
Anyone know if is possible to send commands from client to active directory and how can i disable it if is enable ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "send commands"?

Comment: If i can run powershell script from client to active directory server

Comment: You can run any PowerShell script (including one that connects to AD) from GPO, if that is what you are asking: http://woshub.com/running-powershell-startup-scripts-using-gpo/

Comment: Can i disable this ?

Comment: You can [set the PowerShell execution policy with GPO](https://4sysops.com/archives/set-powershell-execution-policy-with-group-policy/) to restrict the use of PowerShell scripts, but that applies to running *any* PowerShell script, not just one that connects to AD.

Comment: Thanks you . This link help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the [PowerShell execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-6) with GPO to restrict the use of PowerShell scripts. You will find the policy in:

Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows PowerShell

More info [here](https://4sysops.com/archives/set-powershell-execution-policy-with-group-policy/).

But that applies to running any PowerShell script, not just one that connects to AD.